# Function with previous state saving

Tags: javascript

I have a code

```js
var variable = 0;

function add() {
  return variable += 1;
}

console.log(add());
console.log(add());
```

Im wonder is there a way to write this code only using function and scope, smth like

```
function add() {
  /* SET INITIAL STATE IF NOT SET*/
  /* EXECUTE */
  /* RETURN NEW VAL */
}

add(); /* RETURN 1*/
add(); /* RETURN 2*/
```

to get the same result.

Thank you.

Comment: That's called a generator. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) out.

Comment: *"...only using one function..."* But...that *does* use only one function (`add`)....?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess that's a "using only functions" lost in translation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...only using one function...

Your code *does* use only one function (`add`). If you mean you don't want it to close over `variable`, you can store the count elsewhere, for instance as a property on the function itself:

```js
function add() {
  if (!add.variable) {
    add.variable = 0;
  }
  return ++add.variable;
}

console.log(add());
console.log(add());
console.log(add());
```

But of course, that means any code can access and change it.

The usual thing is to close over the variable, and perhaps hide it in a scope where nothing else can see it:

```js
var add = (function() {
  var variable = 0;
  return function add() {
    return ++variable;
  };
})();

console.log(add());
console.log(add());
console.log(add());
```

Comment: Wow... This is interesting... `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar - Someone seems to have downvoted all of them (and the question). Random. It happens. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pseudo static variable for the function:

```js
(() => {
  document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", () => console.log(add(1)));
  function add(n) {
    add.constant = add.constant || 0;
    add.constant += n;
    return add.constant;
  }
})()
```

```html
<button id="test">add 1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also could see the [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) operator ([generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)), or [console.count()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/count)

```js
var add = function () {
  var generate = function *inc() {
    var i = 0
    do {
      i++
      yield i
    } while(true)
  }()
  return function() {
    return generate.next().value
  }
}()

console.log(add())
console.log(add())
console.log(add())
```